# How to convert a Calendar object to an Instant?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8

I have a  `Calendar` object manipulated according to my needs, but converting it to `Instant` is not giving me the correct result:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // creates calendar
cal.setTime(inputFiledate); // sets calendar time/date --> inputFiledate is 29-12-2015
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(inputFileHour)); -->inputFileHour is 5
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,3); // adds  hours that is now time is 29-12-2015 08:00:00
System.out.println("Date after manipulation "+cal.getTime()); -->Displays 
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

// set the time zone with the given time zone value 
// and print it
cal.setTimeZone(tz);
// Date date = cal.getTime(); // returns new date object, one hour in the future
Date d= cal.getTime();
System.out.println("DAte to Instant "+ d.toInstant()); 
System.out.println(" Calendar to Instant "+cal.toInstant());
System.out.println("Date after manipulation2 "+cal.getTime());
```

This is the output:

```
Date after manipulation Tue Dec 29 08:00:00 IST 2015
DAte to Instant 2015-12-29T02:30:00Z
Calendar to Instant 2015-12-29T02:30:00Z
Date after manipulation2 Tue Dec 29 08:00:00 IST 2015
```

In need to convert this Calendar object to instant but it is giving incorrect result 2015-12-29T02:30:00Z
where as the output should be 2015-12-29T08:00:00Z
Where m I going wrong?

Also tried with `Zoned datetime`, with `Timezone`, in vain.

Comment: What do you think `System.out.println("DAte to Instant "+ d.toInstant())` does? How do you think your `Instant` is converted to a `String`?

Comment: I do not see your problem. 08:00:00 in your timezone is 02:30:00 in UTC. So what's wrong?

Comment: @Ctx I think the OP doesn't understand how the `toString` method of `Instant` works...

Comment: I have an Epoch date inputEpochDate that i need to check is lesser than myDate(29 december 8:00:00 one that Ia m calculating using manipulation)
inputFileTime =1451372373 that is 29 december 6:59 
Instant inputEpochDate = Instant.ofEpochSecond( Long.parseLong(inputFileTime ) );
 gives an instant 2015-12-29T06:59:33Z
 where as my Instant returned is 2015-12-29T02:30:00Z and it should actually return 2015-12-29T08:00:00Z

Comment: Let me put it in a simpler way: I need to compare an Epoch time with a Calendar time

Answer (score 1):

Date doesn't have a time zone. From the time difference I assume you are using Indian Time (-5:30) It is just the time relative to epoch which is different in each time zone.

I suggest you do the calculation using `ZonedDateTime` instead of trying to convert from a Calendar.

Comment: It's not so much `Date`, but `Instant`. And it's not so much its lack of a timezone, but the default timezone of the `toString` conversion - which in the case of `Instant` uses `UTC` rather than the system default timezone.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Figuresd Out ZonedDateTime is the only option out: this is how I managed to do the Comparison: LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("29-12-2015",
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH));
  ZonedDateTime zdt = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
  System.out.println(zdt);
  ZonedDateTime zdt1 = zdt.plusHours(5);
  ZonedDateTime zdt2 = zdt1.plusHours(3);

  System.out.println(zdt1);
  System.out.println(zdt2);
  System.out.println(zdt2.toInstant());

  return zdt2.toInstant();

Comment: did not really understand why the question was downvoted though, as it was different from those answered before, I had to compare an Epoch time to another Manipulated time

Comment: @user2176576 I rarely downvote and prefer to comment so there is a chance to learn something.